# the mean and standard deviation aren't the same as those of the input data i provided after sampling

Tags: python, statistics, probability-distribution, scipy.stats

I have a log-normal mean and a standard deviation. after  i converted them to the underlying normal distribution's parameters mu and sigma, I sampled from the log-normal distribution however when i take the mean and standard deviation of this sampled data i don't get the results i plugged in at first. This only happens when the log-normal mean is way smaller than the log-normal standard deviation otherwise it works. how do i prevent this from happening and get the input parameters i plugged in at first?

```
import scipy.stats as stats
from statistics import mean
m = 1.46578E-07
siglog = 1.51
sigma= np.sqrt(np.log(1 + (siglog/m)**2))#normal std
mu= np.log(m) - sigma**2 / 2 #normal mean
x = np.random.lognormal(mu,sigma,1000000)
print(mean(x), np.std(x)) 
[out]: 3.867912662470812e-08 1.0677187655685002e-05
```

Comment: You are squaring (siglog / m) = 10301682. The formulas are correct otherwise.

Comment: @dipetkov any idea how to go around this ? i want to get the same lognormal mean and standard deviation i plugged in at first ?

Comment: You can try the [inverse sampling method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) using the inverse of the cumulative distribution function; that should be the *ppf* function of [scipy.stats.lognorm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html).

Comment: You might still run into numerical issues at which point you should reconsider how plausible it is to sample from the lognormal with mean 1.46578E-07.

Comment: @dipetkov thanks for the suggestion. However implausible the mean i'm working with is, I can only work with it that way since I got it from a database that I'm sure is solid.

Comment: You can also try to sample from the normal distribution and then exponentiate. That actually seems easier as they are probably more algorithms for sampling from the normal.

Comment: I tried that but it gives really bad results, worse than not using it.

Comment: When I plot the density of the lognormal distribution you want to sample from, it's pretty clear it's an edge case. Unless we both got the math wrong. So the "standard" ways to sample from a distribution won't work. Have you considered asking this question on Cross Validated?

Comment: No, I haven't but that's a good idea. I'll do that. thanks

Answer (score 1):

> how do i prevent this from happening and get the input parameters i plugged in at first?

You can prevent this by drawing samples with an infinite number of observations. : P

Joking aside, there is nothing you can do in practice to get the sample mean and sample standard deviation to agree with the population mean and population standard deviation of this distribution. The distributions of the sample mean and sample standard deviation have most of their probability mass to the left of the population mean and population standard deviation, respectively.

Rather than getting into the nitty gritty of the distributions of sample statistics, let's look at this intuitively.

The mean of your underlying normal distribution `mu=-31.88352590476293`, and the standard deviation is `sigma=5.682924912014038`. Consequently, a positive value of the underlying normal distribution is a `(0-mu)/sigma = 5.61` sigma event - very rare; 1 in 100 million. This means that observations from your lognormal that exceed 1 are very rare; indeed, when I ran your code, the largest observation I saw was only ~0.045. Also, keep in mind that the observations will always be positive. As a result, the sample standard deviation you typically observe for a "small" sample (`size=1_000_000`) will be much smaller than `siglog = 1.51` because typical observations range from 0 to some value less than 1.

However, if you took a sample that was large enough, you would be more likely to observe the astonomically large values that would increase the sample standard deviation toward its true population value.

An analogous argument can be made for the sample mean, but the effect is less pronounced.

(Technical point: the sample standard deviation `np.std` is not an unbiased estimator of the population standard deviation. This means that the expected value of the sample standard deviation is not equal to the population standard deviation. Even if [this were fixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation), the distribution of the sample standard deviation would still have most of its mass to the left of the population standard deviation.)